# Can you feed a custom Keras layer with another layer instead of a Tensor?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Let's say I have the custom layer `Node` which inherits from `keras.layers.Layer` and should represent a single node in a neural network.

As far as I know, in order to feed a layer in keras you need to pass a tensor into it, but my desired syntax is something along the lines of:

```
n1 = Node()
n2 = Node()

n2(n1) # Instead of n2(n1.output) where n1.output is a Tensor
```

Is it considered bad practice to do something like that?

Comment: Have you tried checking out the Keras Functional API?

Comment: @mb0850 I am familiar with it, but do you mind explaining what you mean?

Comment: This is not bad practice, just because this code does not work at all,

Answer (score 0):

The **Keras Functional API** is a way to create models that are more flexible than the tf.keras.Sequential API. The functional API can handle models with non-linear topology, shared layers, and even multiple inputs or outputs.

The functional API can be used to create complex graphs of layers.

Lets look at a very simple example:

```
x = layers.Dense(64)(inputs)
x = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(10)(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
```

Here you have 3 layers: `Dense(64) -> Dense(64) -> Dense(10)`, the code first created the 3 layer pipeline and then builds the Model by linking the inputs and outputs.

This is similar to your desired syntax

Refer to the [Tensorflow Keras Functional API Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional)